# Entity Framework with a very large and complex dataset

Tags: performance, entity-framework, ado.net, resources

I would appreciate it very much if you can help me with my questions:

Is EF5 reliable and efficient enough to deal with very large and complex dataset in the real world?

Comparing EF5 with ADO.NET, does EF5 requires significantly more resources such as memory?

For those who have tried EF5 on a real world project with very large and complex dataset, are you happy with the performance so far?

Answer (score 0):

As EF creates an abstraction over the data access. Usage of EF introduces number of additional steps to execute any query. But there are workarounds to reduce the cost. As MS is promoting this ORM, i believe they are doing  alot for performance improvement as well. EF 6 beta is already out. 
There is good article on performance of EF5 available on MSDN for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

I will not use EF if lot of complex manipulations and iterations are required on the DBsets after populating the DBSets from the EF query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would argue that there are not 'workarounds' but 'correct ways of using it'

Comment: First of all, I appreciate all your answers, they are useful to me. My project would involve a lot of complex manipulations and iterations - each client request involves X iterations; each iteration requires searches and multiple inserts/updates. Many clients doing this requests around the same time. I'm rather new with both EF & ADO.NET... just want to pick your brains on this.

Answer (score 0):

EF is more than capable of handling large amounts of data. Just as in plain ADO.NET, you need to understand how to use it correctly. Its just as easy to write code in ADO.NET that performs poorly. Its also important to remember that EF is built on top of ADO.NET.

DBSets will be much slower with large amounts of data than a code first EF approach. Plain Datareaders could be faster if done correctly.

The correct answer is 'profile'. Code some large objects and profile the differences.

Comment: Thanks... yes... profiling would help me determine the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research into this on EF 4.1 and some details might still apply though there have been upgrades in performance to EF5 to keep in mind.

[ADO vs EF performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103379/entity-framework-4-1-vs-enterprise-data-application-block-maximum-performance)

My conclusions:
-You won't match ADO performance with a framework that has to generate the actual SQL statement dynamically from C# and turn that sql statement into a strongly typed object, there is simply too much going on, even with pre compiled and 'warmed' statements (and performance tests conclude this). This is a happy trade off for many who find it much easier to write and maintain Linq in C# than stored procs and mapping code.

-You can still use stored procedures with equal performance to ADO which to me is the perfect situation. You can write linq to sql in situations where it works, and as soon as you would like more performance, write the sproc and import it to EF to enjoy the best performance possible.

-There is no technical reason to avoid EF accept for the requirements of your project and possibly your teams knowledge and comfort level. Be sure to make sure it fits into your selected design pattern.. [EF Anti Patterns to avoid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx)

I hope this helps.